# Contact form does not send message to Gmail account

Tags: php, email

I have a form on a client website that upon submission I get a successful message but it doesn't send any information to the Gmail account on file. I filled out the form once and I successfully received that email but when I tried again none of the other emails were coming through. This form has been working just fine until now.

I've tried fixing `the SMTP configurations` but that didn't work. The messages aren't going to my spam folder and there aren't any email filters in my Gmail account. Please this is not a duplicate post, i really need some help with this.

```php
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

    $fname = $_POST['template-jobform-fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['template-jobform-lname'];
    $email = $_POST['template-jobform-email'];
    $company = $_POST['template-jobform-company'];
    $country = $_POST['template-jobform-country'];
    $phone = $_POST['template-jobform-phone'];
    $website = $_POST['template-jobform-website'];
    $position = $_POST['template-jobform-position'];
    $mw = $_POST['template-jobform-mw'];
    $location = $_POST['template-jobform-location'];
    $timeline = $_POST['template-jobform-timeline'];
    $application = $_POST['template-jobform-application'];
    
    $name = $fname . ' ' . $lname;

    $subject = 'Quote';

    $botcheck = $_POST['template-jobform-botcheck'];

    $toemail = '[REDACTED]@gmail.com'; // Your Email Address
    $toname = 'Website Quote Form'; // Your Name

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->SetFrom( $email, $name );
        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
        $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $fname $lname<br><br>" : '';
        $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
        $company = isset($company) ? "Company: $company<br><br>" : '';
        $country = isset($country) ? "Country: $country<br><br>" : '';
        $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
        $website  = isset($website) ? "Website: $website <br><br>" : '';
        $position = isset($position) ? "Interested Product: $position<br><br>" : '';
        $mw = isset($mw) ? "Total MW: $mw<br><br>" : '';
        $location = isset($location) ? "Location: $location<br><br>" : '';
        $timeline = isset($timeline) ? "Timeline: $timeline<br><br>" : '';
        $application = isset($application) ? "Message: $application<br><br>" : '';

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

        $body = "$name $email $company $country $phone $website $position $mw $location $timeline $application";

        if ( isset( $_FILES['template-jobform-cvfile'] ) && $_FILES['template-jobform-cvfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-jobform-cvfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-jobform-cvfile']['name'] );
        }

        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

        if( $sendEmail == true ):
            echo 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your request and will respond to you as soon as possible.';
        else:
            echo 'Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '';
        endif;
    } else {
        echo 'Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later.';
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the code in it. Don't post images of code.

Comment: Check the phpmailer troubleshooting guide and turn on debug mode

Comment: I figured it out! I had to create an app password in my google account and use that instead of the google password as, Gmail no longer gives access to its accounts with just username and password.

Answer (score -1):

See this code

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <h3>LEAVE US A MESSAGE</h3>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required autoComplete="off"/>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required autoComplete="off"/>
  <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required autoComplete="off" cols="4" rows="8" ></textarea>
  <button>Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Read [answer]. Just dumping code without an explanation is not useful. Explain how it would solve the problem.